# Adaptar o entrada do utilizador para o tamanho de um array

Tags: java, array

Criei um programa que gera labirintos possíveis de serem solucionados, mas agora não estou a conseguir implementar uma maneira de o tamanho do labirinto gerado ser definido pelo utilizador.

O código em baixo é o `ActionListener` de um botão que quando clicado pergunta ao utilizador o tamanho, e eu transformei o input numa int

```
static class thehandler2 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        String row = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insira o nº de linhas: ", "Question", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        String col = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insira o nº de colunas: ", "Question", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        int foo = Integer.parseInt(row);
        int foo2 = Integer.parseInt(col);
        Maze_Generator.Gera_maze_final();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Maze_Generator view = new Maze_Generator();
                view.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

O problema é que eu inicialmente criei o array grid que contem o labirinto como uma variável global da classe `Maze_Generator`, pois preciso de usar o array grid várias vezes dentro de outras subclasses da classe `Maze_Generator`, e agora não consigo arranjar maneira de fazer com que a variável `row = foo` e `col = foo2`.

```
public class Maze_Generator extends JFrame {
private static int row = 9;
private static int col = 9;
public static char[][] grid = new char[row][col];
public static List<Integer> l = new LinkedList<Integer>();
public static int pathIndex;

public Maze_Generator() {
    setTitle("Maze");
    setSize(640,480);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void Gera_maze_final() {
    int k = 0;
    while (true && k<100 ) {
        k+=1;
        if (l.size()==0&& k<100) {
            Maze_Generator.Gera_maze();
            char[][] maze = grid;
            Maze_Resolve_Gerada.Buscar(maze);
            int numrow = grid.length;
            int numcol = grid[0].length;
            boolean[][] checked = new boolean[numrow][numcol];
            DepthFirst.searchPath(maze, 1, 0, l, checked);
            pathIndex = l.size() - 2;
            //System.out.println(l.toString());

            }
        }

    }

public static void Gera_maze() {

    String AB = "_W";

    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            char c = AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length()));
            grid[i][j] = c;
            grid[0][1] = 'S';
            grid[7][7] = 'E';

        }
    }

    for (char[] r : grid) {
        for (char c : r) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


    }

}
```

Não coloquei aqui o código todo da classe `Maze_Generator` para o problema ser especifico, mas se for necessário o restante código eu meto.

Comment: você se refere ao array `grid`?

Comment: sim, é esse mesmo

Comment: O que é esse geramazefinal??

Comment: é uma sub classe que pega no array grid depois de criado e resolve o labirinto

Comment: Mas porque você ta chamando ele antes de criar uma instancia de Maze_Generator? O código não está fazendo muito sentido pra mim.

Comment: como disse que não meti aqui o código todo, mas quando eu chamo a subclasse geramazefinal ele tem lá dentro Maze_Generator.Gera_maze(); que vai buscar o array grid criado anteriormente

Comment: Mas você está criando um array estático ja de cara, ai não tem como alterar mais depois. Eu ia sugerir criar um construtor pegando os dados capturados, mas para isso, `grid` não pode ser static.

Comment: já meti todo o código da classe Maze_Generator no post inical

Comment: O problema é misturar variaveis estatica com de instancia. Como eu disse, você poderia tornar `grid` nao estatica,  e passar os valores no construtor da classe `Maze_Generator` já criando o array com esse tamanho definido pelo usuario. Mas sendo estatica, não tem jeito, só criando outro array estatico após capturar os dados, já que tamanho de arrays são imutaveis.

Comment: algo como isto? public static void captura_dados(int row, int col) {
        char[][] teste = new char[row][col];
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendo em conta as dicas anteriores e alguma pesquisa, encontrei a seguinte solução para o meu problema anterior:

```
public static int getRow() {
    String nrow = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insira o nº de linhas: ", "Question", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    int  row = Integer.parseInt(nrow);
    return row;
}

public static int getCol() {
    String ncol = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insira o nº de colunas: ", "Question", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    int  col = Integer.parseInt(ncol);
    return col;
}

private static int frow = getRow();
private static int fcol = getCol();
public static char[][] grid = new char[frow][fcol];
```

Percebi que como o array grid criado anteriormente era static, só aceitava int static, por isso resolvi criar duas funções static: getRow() e getCol() que retornam ambas int static que serão aceites no array grid.